# How to connect a cassandra(version 3.11.4) node from other node?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am setting up two nodes, one node where cassandra is running and other node where my spring-boot service is running which uses cassandra database. I am unable to connect to the cassandra node from other service node(tried with- telnet 'cassandra node ip' 'cassandra port number'). I tried with modifying cassandra.yml. I changed "listen_address" and "rpc_address" to node address but cassandra is not starting with this configuration(Connection refused). Is there any other configuration i need to do? Java version-8, Cassandra version- 3.11.4.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't telnet to it, then you definitely won't be able to connect to it. Are you sure there are no firewalls in place? On the cassandra server you're trying to telnet to, can you run:

netstat -nap | grep 9042 | grep LISTEN

Whatever port you specified for your native_transport_port in cassandra.yaml.

or

lsof -i TCP | grep cassandraPid | grep LISTEN"

Where the "cassandraPid" is the process ID of the cassandra process

Can you connect using cqlsh on the cassandra host when specifying the host and port? If you can, then there is a firewall blocking your client server. If not, then again, check your port settings.

Comment: Hello Jim, I did netstat, it shows
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12315/java.
isof command shows
java      12315       cassandra  134u  IPv4 505440      0t0  TCP *:9042 (LISTEN)
also I am unable to connect using cqlsh. Can you please specify what are the configurations i have to do in yml file. May be I am missing something.

Comment: So from the output I can see that your cassandra is indeed listening on port 9042. Can you list the exact "cqlsh" command you're issuing? What linux platform are you running? If RH 7 or something similar, you may want to try to shut down firewalld (or iptables if RH 6) if it's running (just as a quick check to see if it's causing problems). Can you telnet from the localhost to the 9042 and host you're specifying? As I can see your cassandra is listening on 9042, there is definitely something "blocking" the path to your host.